# What does "electronic verbatim record" mean?

Tags: administrative-law, court-records

What does "electronic verbatim record" mean, and how is it different from "written" in the [following](http://www.p12.nysed.gov/specialed/lawsregs/sect2005.htm):

(v) A written or, at the option of the parents, electronic verbatim record of the proceedings before the impartial hearing officer shall be maintained and made available to the parties.

I'm wondering if it has something to do with audio recordings (which I requested, but was told were not permitted).

There was a court reporter.  I have a copy of the transcripts made by the court reporter.  They have a lot of mistakes.

Comment: By law, there can't be mistakes in the transcript. That doesn't mean the transcript is correct, it's just that you have no recourse if you dispute the transcript, because reporters are presumed to not make mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verbatim, despite sounding like verbal, only means that it is an exact account of what was said during the proceedings. Thus appending electronic to it means that this exact record is available in some electronic form, like as a Word or PDF document - however they store it electronically. So it is simply stating you can get the verbatim record in either written or electronic form, depending on your preference.

Comment: I forgot to say, I also have an electronic version (pdf) which the reporter's agency kindly sent me.  It's hard to do copy and paste, because there's a carriage return at the end of every line. // So it definitely does not mean an audio recording?

Comment: @aparente001 No, there is nothing in that wording that suggests they would be required to give you any audio or video recording of the proceedings.