# Why are electronic and photorecording devices prohibited in courtrooms?

Tags: recording, court, court-records

Observers in open court hearings often must resort to taking notes by hand and making pencil sketches.

In the US we often see limited snippets of video footage on TV, and yet, there is still the tradition of court trial drawings with pencils and pastels.

What is behind the ban on photo or video recording devices even as it may seem to be eroding in some jurisdictions and locales?

Comment: Which jurisdiction? Also, OJ simpson was tried live on TV

Comment: Mainly UK but it's a general question because if it wasn't valid to at least some degree then we wouldn't have such a big tradition of court artists.

Comment: Sorry, while this is a good question it is off topic here. Law.SE is for questions about what the law *is*. Questions about *why* belong on Politics.SE. Flagged for moderator attention.

Comment: [Relevant answers here](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/37122/10).